# Progressbar in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-progressbar

I have `progressbar`, download button inside `gridview`. When `gridview` loads `progressbar` are invisible. When I tap on download `button`, `progressbar` should appear with corresponding position and download should start. I did all these. But progress bar shuffles when I move the `gridview` up and down. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.
I did this much in `getview` method of `ArrayAdapter`.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridviewcell, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        viewHolder.progressBar=(ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_grid);
        viewHolder.tv_ot_edition_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ot_edition_name);
        viewHolder.tv_edition_description = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ot_edition_description);
        viewHolder.downloadbutton = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgBtnbookdownload);

        viewHolder.progressBar  = (ProgressBar) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.progressBar_grid);

        viewHolder.book_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        //viewHolder.listener = new ItemClickListener() ;
         convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
         convertView.setTag(R.id.progressBar_grid, viewHolder.progressBar);
         viewHolder.downloadbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    int getPosition = (Integer) viewHolder.progressBar.getTag();

                //  books.get(getPosition).setSelected(v.isSelected());
                    books.get(getPosition).setSelected(true);
                    MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity(GridviewDemo.this);
                    mainActivity.startdownload(viewHolder.progressBar);
                    viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.progressBar.setTag(position); 
    viewHolder.tv_ot_edition_name.setText(books.get(position).getOt_edition_name());

    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "HelveticaBold.ttf");
    viewHolder.tv_ot_edition_name.setTypeface(face);
    viewHolder.tv_edition_description.setTypeface(face);
    viewHolder.tv_edition_description.setText(books.get(position)
            .getOt_edition_description()
            );  

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(books.get(position)
            .getImage_url(), 0, books.get(position).getImage_url().length);

    viewHolder.book_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    //  viewHolder.downloadbutton.setOnClickListener(viewHolder.listener) ;
    viewHolder.downloadbutton.setImageResource(books.get(position)
            .getDownloadbtn_resid());
    final BookData data = (BookData)getItem(position) ;
    //viewHolder.listener.setId(data.getId()) ;
    //viewHolder.listener.setHolder(viewHolder) ;
    //viewHolder.progressBar.setProgress(data.getProcess()) ;

    return convertView; 
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind showing what you did, add some code.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Please go through the edited post. Its getView() method

Comment: Ok Good, what did you mean by "But progress bar shuffles when I move the gridview up and down"? Means misalignment of the layout? And  viewHolder.progressBar  = (ProgressBar) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.progressBar_grid);
Is the progressBar_grid's visiblity set as gone in the xml file?

Comment: No misalignment of the layout. Every other views are perfect. Only Progressbar does n't appeared for the tapped download button. Instead Progressbar appears in the next pages when scroll down/up. I repeat its pages. I think it is happening because of view recycling. Yeah Progressbar set as 'GONE'

Comment: I am following this link http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Comment: Ok.. you rightly identified ti as the recycle issue. Hope you are using an array to track the visiblity of the views.

Comment: I am using the ArrayList. But I do not know how to use it inside getView recycling to track visibility of the progressbar. I bit confused

Answer (score -1):

> When gridview loads progressbar are invisible

Set the visibility to `View.INVISIBLE` or `View.GONE`.

> When I tap on download button, progressbar should appear with
>   corresponding position and download should start.

Set the visibility to `View.Visible`. Set the progress bar using the `setProgress()` or `incrementProgressBy()` methods of the `ProgressBar`

Comment: I tried the same also. But Progressbar appears in the next pages when scroll down/up. I repeat its next pages. I think it is happening because of view recycling.